# How to migrate stored procedure response as a table from Sybase into MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sybase

In my Sybase DB, I have this stored procedure which gives me the list of employees.

```
/*
    exec SpGetStaffData   null
*/
create procedure dbo.SpGetStaffData
    as

begin
            select
                   EmpCode,
                   FirstName,
                   LastName
            from HRM..employees
end
return 0
```

I want to migrate the data into a table in MSSQL Server DB

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Seems fairly straightforward: you can use the Import?Export Wizard in SSMS. And the procedure syntax is the same in this particular case. What have you tried so far? And how is C# relevant?

Comment: @Charlieface Can you use SSMS Import Wizard to import from a stored procedure? If so, how do you do this? I thought you could only import from Tables and Views?  If the OP only has access to the SP, then I would be tempted to write a little c# console app, to read the data from the Sybase SP into a `DataTable`, and then upload to MSSQL via `SqlBulkCopy`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this via a linked server that you create inside a MS SQL Server instance, let's call it SybLinkedServer:

```
INSERT INTO #temptab EXEC SybLinkedServer..dbo.SpGetStaffData
go
```